# How can get the previous and next date in line with each ID's date in table_1 from table_2?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp, subquery

I am trying to get the first timestamp (in table_2) previous and next to each date (from table_1) that has an event.
It is sometimes a few second before and after and sometimes hours or days.

My table_1 looks like:

```
|-------|------------------|-------------|
|    id |       date       |    events   |
|-------|------------------|-------------|
|     4 |2020-04-11 3:44:20|     call    |
|     2 |2020-04-21 7:59:06| appointment |
|     1 |2020-04-17 1:14:32| appointment |
|     3 |2020-04-10 3:41:17|   feedback  |
|-------|------------------|-------------|
```

Table_2 looks like:

```
|------------------|-------------|
|       date       |    events   |
|------------------|-------------|
|2020-04-13 3:07:13|   feedback  |
|------------------|-------------|
|2020-04-12 5:42:04|   feedback  |
|------------------|-------------|
|2020-04-18 2:52:11|     call    |
|------------------|-------------|
|2020-04-21 8:14:27| appointment |
|------------------|-------------|
```

And this is the result I am looking for:

```
|----------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    id    |       date       |   previous_date     |    next_date     |
|----------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     4    |2020-04-11 3:44:20| 2020-04-12 5:42:04  |2020-04-12 5:42:04|
|----------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     2    |2020-04-21 7:59:06| 2020-04-18 2:52:11  |2020-04-21 8:14:27|
|----------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     1    |2020-04-17 1:14:32| 2020-04-13 3:07:13  |2020-04-18 2:52:11|
|----------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     3    |2020-04-13 3:02:17| 2020-04-12 5:42:04  |2020-04-13 3:07:13|
|----------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

Any help would be appreciated. My table is way bigger then this of course.

This is what I am playing around with but with no success:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.date,
    (
     SELECT MIN(t1.date)
        FROM table_1 AS t1
        WHERE t1.date > t2.date
            AND t1.events = t2.events
    ) AS NextDate
    FROM table_2 t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem probably is that you aliased both tables `t2` in your query.

That said, it does look like subqueries would get the job done here. From your data, you don’t want to correlate on `event`, only on the date:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.date,
    (
        SELECT MAX(t2.date)
        FROM table_2 AS t2
        WHERE t2.date < t1.date
    ) AS PreviousDate,
    (
        SELECT MIN(t2.date)
        FROM table_2 AS t2
        WHERE t2.date > t1.date
    ) AS NextDate
FROM table_1 t1
```